# Migrate MySQL data to Elasticsearch through Logstash with Many-to-Many associations

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

Trying to create data migration from my MySQL db to Elasticsearch index using Logstash.

I have this kind of db schema:

[image: My db schema]

`item` here is the main table. I intend to search `item`s.
Each `item` has `city`.
It has many `colours`.
It has many `specifications`, each of one has some `value` being set in join-table.

Currently I've succeded migration only for `city` by combining it to `item` table by `LEFT JOIN`.

My migration statement looks like this:

```
statement => "SELECT `item`.`id`, `item`.`title`, `item`.`description`, `city`.`name` AS `city` FROM `item` LEFT JOIN `city` ON `city`.`id` = `item`.`city`"
```

My whole `logstach.conf`:

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    jdbc_driver_library => "/some/local/path/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT `item`.`id`, `item`.`title`, `item`.`description`, `city`.`name` AS `city` FROM `item` LEFT JOIN `city` ON `city`.`id` = `item`.`city`"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "test-migrate"
  "document_type" => "data"
  "document_id" => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Wonder how can I migrate `colour` and `specification` with its `value` to search my `item` by these properties too?

For example, if there is an `item`, which associated with `city` = 'London', and with `colour` = 'blue' and with `colour` = 'red' and with `colour` = 'yellow', and associated with `specification` = 'material' with `value` = 'ceramic', it should be found by "London AND blue AND ceramic" and "London AND red AND ceramic" search queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to join remaining tables and get their values like below -

```
SELECT item.id, 
    item.title, 
    item.description, 
    city.name AS city,
    spec.name as specificationName,
    ispec.value as specificationValue,
    color.name as color 
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN city ON city.id = item.city
LEFT JOIN Item_has_Color ic on ic.item = item.id
LEFT JOIN Item_has_Specification as ispec on ispec.item = item.id
LEFt JOIN color on color.id = ic.color 
LEFT JOIN specification as spec on spec.id = ispec.specification
```

Comment: Ok, that's the answer. Thanks for a clue! All you need to do next is: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example4